# List index out of range for price check

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to check Bitcoin prices movement in Binance Exchange:

```
import keys
import datetime
from time import sleep
from binance.client import Client
import certifi
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
    cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
    ca_certs=certifi.where())

client = Client(keys.APIKey, keys.SecretKey)
# client = Client(keys.APIKey, keys.SecretKey, {"verify": True, "timeout": 20})
# client.get_all_orders(symbol='BTCUSDT', requests_params={'timeout': 5})

symbol= 'BTCUSDT'
quantity= '0.003'

order= False
while order==False:
    BTC= client.get_historical_klines(symbol=symbol, interval='30m', 
                                      start_str="1 hour ago UTC")
    if (float(BTC[-1][4])-float(BTC[-2][4]))>500:
        print ('Buyyy')
        client.order_market_buy(symbol= symbol, quantity= quantity)
        order= True
    elif (float(BTC[-1][4])-float(BTC[-2][4]))<-500:
        print ('Sellll')
        client.order_market_buy(symbol= symbol , quantity= quantity)
        order= True
    else:
        print ('Do nothing')
    sleep(10)
```

But I get this error message:

> File "xxx\trading.py", line 30, in
>   
>       if len(float(BTC[-1][4])-float(BTC[-2][4]))>500:
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I don't understand how checking for a movement between two time periods of $500 return this error?

I don't see how I can use len() in this case as well.

Comment: What does `BTC`'s value?

Comment: Let's say period -2 = $7,000 and period -1 = $7,500, then trigger a buy signal and vice versa

Comment: your Index is out of range, so when you try to access `BTC[-1][4]` , for example, it couldn't find anything in that position.

Comment: ok, it is because the API is not connecting or it's working fine but there is no value to show with the above statement?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, thank you @benja d!

I had to change:

```
start_str="1 hour ago UTC")
```

to

```
start_str="1 day ago UTC")
```